# Unable to create nodejs serverless project

Tags: node.js, cloud, serverless

I am new to serverless framework. I tried to install serverless framework (latest version: 3.25.1) and created a nodejs project using "serverless create --template aws-nodejs --path ." command, but I got an error:

```
Environment: win32, node 16.16.0, framework 3.25.1, plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com

Error:
Could not download template. Ensure that you are using the latest version of Serverless 
Framework: The server aborted pending request
```

I followed all steps in the documentation. I would appreciate it if anyone could solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall serverless globally first
Then install again the latest version of serverless
Ten try without you VPN to create a new project